# Minimum Vertex Cover of 2 vertex disjoint but connected odd cycles.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Consider the graph G, which is comprised of 2 vertex disjoint **odd** cycles (C1, C2) where |C1| & |C2| >= 5. **G is sub-cubic and connected**, with edges in between the cycles. Because G is sub-cubic, each node's degree <=3 but >=2.

I am interested to know whether the minimum vertex cover of G can be found in polynomial time?
Furthermore, I am also interested to know whether we can:

1. Establish a tight upper bound on the MinVC for such a graph.
2. Say anything else about this graph that's insightful.

We know that for either cycle C, minVC = (|C|+1)/2. Thus, minVC(G) >= (|C1|+1)/2 + (|C2|+1)/2

A loose upper bound would be to take all vertices of one cycle and solve optimally for the other. Thus, minVC(G) <= min(|C1|,|C2|) + (max(|C1|, |C2|)+1)/2.

Comment: Please clarify your construction of $G$. Vertex-disjoint odd cycles sounds disconnected but you say it is connected. Do the two odd cycles include (between them) all vertices of $G$, with some edges added between the cycles to make a connected graph?

Comment: Yes the odd cycles include all vertices of G between them and there are edges added between the cycles that make G connected. Note, G must be sub-cubic, so degree of each vertex is <=3.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum vertex cover of a disconnected graph is *trivially* the union of the minimum vertex covers of the components.

Comment: The graph is connected and sub-cubic, as mentioned in the description.

Comment: @Dabbler But $G$ is comprised of two disjoint cycles. Therefore your conditions are contradictory.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel therefore you should have put up a comment for clarification, not an answer.